# How to convert a Dataframe value stored as an array to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which all of the values are stored as an array in one of the columns.
I want to take this array and do the following:

- Remove all carriage returns from each value in the array
- Split each item in the array into a separate line.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
          group         email
0         c             'samuel.tom@example.com / samuel tom\rkate.leo@example.com / kate leo\rbilly.billerson@example.com',nan
```

When I types `df["email"].values`, I see the following:

```
array(['samuel.tom@example.com / samuel tom\rkate.leo@example.com / kate leo\rbilly.billerson@example.com',nan], dtype=object
```

What I need to do, is produce the following:

```
      group         email
0         c          samuel.tom@example.com / samuel tom
0         c          kate.leo@example.com / kate leo
0         c          billy.billerson@example.com
0         c          nan
```

I found another post that explained how to split the values vertically, and it works, just not for this particular case.

I **think** what I need to do is convert the array into a list, remove all of the carriage returns from this new value, and then split everything vertically.

I tried to convert the value into a list by doing this:

```
open_appended_file["Members"] = open_appended_file["Members"].tolist()
```

But this still shows the values listed as being an array.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) if need splitting by `\r`:

```
df = df.assign(email = df['email'].str.split('\r')).explode('email').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  group                                email
0     c  samuel.tom@example.com / samuel tom
1     c      kate.leo@example.com / kate leo
2     c          billy.billerson@example.com
3     c                                  NaN
```

Comment: This works, but I'd like to understand why it works.

why do I need to use ".str."? Isn't the datatype already a string data type? Is ".str." simply converting it to a string?

Comment: @LunchBox - It is `str` accessor, [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html), not for convert to string, but for use pandas text function.